# Transform string in a list with elements separated on Python

Tags: python, serial-port, hex

I have a string:

u = "01 a0 32 00 00 00 00 fe 12 6f 04"

and I'd like to transform it, using Python3, on:

[0x01,0xa0,0x32,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xfe,0x12,0x6f,0x04]

My propose is that user write a string of hex values and I'll send it to serial port.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `[int(x, 16) for x in u.split()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more-useful transformation is likely to turn it into `bytes`:

```
rem_spaces = str.maketrans({' ':None})

from binascii import unhexlify

unhexlify(u.translate(rem_spaces))
Out[13]: b'\x01\xa02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x12o\x04'
```

Or alternately a `bytearray`:

```
bytearray(int(x,16) for x in u.split())
Out[14]: bytearray(b'\x01\xa02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x12o\x04')
```

If you really want a `list` of `int`s:

```
[int(x, 16) for x in u.split()]
Out[22]: [1, 160, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 254, 18, 111, 4]
```

But in my experience you will very likely want to just work with sending/receiving `bytes`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, roippi!
The way it works for me was the bytearray solution.
Now I can proceed with my propose.
Thank you again!

Comment: UH! What I did first was transform the string into a list with var=var.split(), after that I made the bytearray.